# Set Typeface for CheckboxPreference

Tags: android

I want to set font for `CheckBoxPreference`. I know that we can set font for `CheckBox` using `setTypeface` method. But, CheckBoxPreference class has not typeface method.

Could any one please guide me to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating your own subclass of `CheckBoxPreference`, overriding `onBindView()` and updating the typeface in there.